# PowerShell - How to use a $_.Key as $object property?

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable like so:

```
$hash = @{
    One="One"
    Two="Two"
    Three="Three"
    }
```

Doing this does not work:

```
$hash.getEnumerator() | foreach {
  $object.$_.Key = $_.Value
}
```

However this words:

```
$hash.getEnumerator() | foreach {
  $test = $_.Key
  $object.$test = $_.Value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PowerShell allows you to use *expressions* as property names**, which is what you successfully used in `$object.$test`: the value of variable `$test` served as the property name.

However, depending on the complexity of the expression, **you may need `(...)`** to delineate it:

Therefore, you must use `$object.($_.Key)` rather than `$object.$_.Key` - the latter would be interpreted as *nested* property access.

---

Taking a step back:

PowerShell allows you to construct and initialize types that have a parameter-less constructor and public properties directly from a hashtable; e.g. (PSv5+):

```bash
# Type (class) with parameterless constructor and public properties.
class Foo {
  [string] $Bar
  [int]    $Baz
}

# Instantiate [Foo] and set its properties from a hashtable
$newFoo = [Foo] @{ Baz = 42; Bar = 'none' }
```